# How can I use JSON objects more than once?

Tags: ios, json, oop

This is hard for me to explain so let me just give you all an example.

Say you're creating a game and you want store information about of list of skills such as: blacksmithing, carpentry, etc... Then you have a list of items that can be made pertaining to the skills: copper dagger, wood plank, etc.. And each of those items have several different ingredients which contain other information such as quantity.

How would you go about storing this information using JSON in neat format considering that some items may have the same ingredients?

```
{"skill":[
  "blacksmithing":{
     "items":[
       {"copper dagger":{
         "ingredients":[] // this where i get lost because i feel like its too complicated after this point
       }},
       // and so on
      ]
   },
  "carpentry":{
     "items":[]
  }
]}
```

I've never really created any JSON files myself so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. I don't even know if JSON is the correct way to approach this.. I'm just trying to create an iOS application and a web application that would read this information in, parse it, and create the objects accordingly.

Comment: There is no such thing as JSON object

Comment: Technically, you are right. But in the grand scheme of things, I want to turn them into objects via whichever language I decide to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can try:- (instead of taking "copper dagger" as a separate object , you can put it as a key-value pair with "name" as key & "copper dagger" as value)

```
"blacksmithing":{
 "items":[
   {"name" : "copper dagger", "ingredients":[{}, {}]},
   // and so on
  ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was doing something wrong. What if the ingredients of another item are the same of this item. Is there any way to link them rather than having redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using DocumentDirectory to save .plist file or .json file, saving there is persistent, you can then easily get the stored information in an array by read the file like:

```
NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile
```

You can easily find more information about that method either here on stack or in apples documentation.Simply summarized: you need to alloc a file manager, then get the path to the documentDirectory, and after that save the needed file with FileManager in that directory.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that. I love learning new approaches to problems.